# Permissions Error (errno13) on application

Tags: python, permission-denied

There's this snipe bot I've been trying to use. When I try and open the main.py it results in the errno13 error. The path is "C:\Users\jackg\Downloads\ugc-sniper-main\main.py".
Here's the full error.

```
ERROR:root:An error occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jackg\Downloads\ugc-sniper-main\main.py", line 33, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logs.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 2050, in basicConfig
    h = FileHandler(filename, mode,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1181, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1213, in _open
    return open_func(self.baseFilename, self.mode,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\logs.txt'
```

> And yes, when I went to **Properties > Security** it has full control. I am using Windows 11, thank you very much.

I tried reinstalling python and ticked both of the boxes, Still the same error.

Comment: It's attempting to log to the current working directory. The code assumes that the current working directory is writable. I would suggest changing directory to a directory which is writable. Example command prompt command for changing working directory: `cd C:\Users\jackg\Downloads\ugc-sniper-main`

Comment: Yeah I copied the path of the main.py sorry, It's directory is ""C:\Users\jackg\Downloads\ugc-sniper-main""